# how to insert values in table in cake php

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

here i done code for contact us page with two fileds like email,body it stores values in db
but it s  not working i post the code here

**Model**

```
 //model/pages.php
    <?php 
    class pages extends AppModel{
        var $useTable = 'contact';

        }
    ?>
```

**Controller**

```
    class PagesController extends AppController {

    public $uses = array();


    public function display() {
        $path = func_get_args();

        $count = count($path);
        if (!$count) {
            return $this->redirect('/');
        }
        $page = $subpage = $title_for_layout = null;

        if (!empty($path[0])) {
            $page = $path[0];
        }
        if (!empty($path[1])) {
            $subpage = $path[1];
        }
        if (!empty($path[$count - 1])) {
            $title_for_layout = Inflector::humanize($path[$count - 1]);
        }
        $this->set(compact('page', 'subpage', 'title_for_layout'));

        try {
            $this->render(implode('/', $path));
        } catch (MissingViewException $e) {

            if (Configure::read('debug')) {
                throw $e;
            }
            throw new NotFoundException();
        }
    }
    public function index(){
        $this->set('post', $this->contact->find('all'));
        }

    public function create() {
        if ($this->request->is('post'))
//this function for methods like get, post, set,delelte
         {
            // print_r('post');


$this->contact->create();
        if ($this->contact->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your post has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to add your post.'));
        }
    }
}
```

**view**
here code for display

```
view/contact.ctp
<?php

echo 'welcome to Contact us';

echo $this->Form->create('pages');
echo $this->Form->input('email');
echo $this->Form->input('body', array('rows' => '6'));
echo $this->Form->end('Save pages');


?>
```

added in db table and values  contact

Comment: Version of `CakePHP`?

Comment: this is cakephp-2.4.5.0 @PauloRodrigues

Comment: `class pages` as model? Inside the PagesController? You really should start reading the book and its tutorials first.. Conventions are important - especially at the beginning. Or if you are asking for help.

Comment: am biggener to cake php so i stared practices so i asked help @mark

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you read something to start in **CakePHP** like [Getting Started](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started.html) or [CakePHP Conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html)?

Reading some documentation, you will find that your tables should be named in plural and models in singular. Your model in `app/Model/Contact.php` looks like this:

```
class Contact extends AppModel {
    public $useTable = 'contacts'; // It is not necessary, because CakePHP implicitly understands that your table will be in the plural
}
```

Now, your view located in `app/View/Contacts/index.ctp`:

```
echo $this->Form->create('Contact');
echo $this->Form->input('email');
echo $this->Form->input('body', array('rows' => '6'));
echo $this->Form->end('Save');
```

And your controller in `app/Controller/ContactsController.php`:

```
class ContactsController extends AppController {
    public function index() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->Contact->create();

            if ($this->Contact->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your contact has been saved.'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to add your contact.'));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is a basic usage. I recommend you read the documentation to start with CakePHP because it has lots of interesting things that you may need.